# Workstation VM unable to start after import on ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation, export, import

I've been given a folder of a VM (with .vmdk, .vmx, ...), created and used in VMWare Workstation. I want to use it on my VMWare ESXi.

How do I correctly import the VM?

I've tried to import it, by copying the folder to the ESXi datastore, then 
`Create/Register VM`, `Register an existing virtual machine` and finally choose the `.vmx` file of the copied folder.

The adding of the VM appears to work just fine, but when I try to start it, ESXi states:

```
Failed to open disk scsi0:0: Unsupported or invalid disk type 7. Ensure that the disk has been imported.
Unable to create virtual SCSI device for scsi0:0, '/<disk-store>/import/<the-workstation-folder>/<target-vm>.vmdk'
Module DevicePowerOn power on failed.
Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

In the settings of the new ESXI VM, I see that the path is correct and the virtual disk file is really in that location.

Is there another way to import the VM? Do I have to modify the disk settings on the ESXi?

*I have no access to VMWare Workstation, where the VM was originally created/used.*

Comment: Why didn't you just export it as an OVF/OVA?

Comment: @Chopper3 See the question, I've been given the folder only and I don't have access to the Workstation, where the VM was originally created/used.

Comment: Oh well you're out of luck then - no solution.

Comment: @Chopper3 no, not really. A viable solution has been posted by Gerald Schneider, as you can see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VMware Workstation VMs are not compatible to ESXi. VMware Workstation uses different virtual hardware than ESXi.

The easiest way is to convert the VM using [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html).

Comment: And what is the solution when the **Hardware compatibility** is explicitly set to ESXi X.Y virtual machine?

Comment: @TheThirstyApe you should ask a question about that. Please provide more concrete information about your case when you do.

Answer (score 4):

As another option, you can use [StarWind V2V](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter) that also converts VMware Workstation VM image to ESXi one.